# XSS filter evasion

Tags: xss

if `<>` tags are html-escaped but `"` is not escaping, can I have xss? I have already tried `" onmouseover="alert('xss');"` but doesn't seem like it is working. I have a feeling that xss resides in it because all characters are not properly escaped.

Below is the exact HTML:

```
<p class="messageText" style="max-height: 250px; overflow-y: auto;" id="body-9">" onmouseover=alert('xss');" </p>
```

Comment: Where is your code is injected? In an attribute or outside of a tag?

Comment: you need to be in a tag to exploit an attribute, and if you can't start a tag, I don't see a vector.